# Rails from directory of application doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler

I have installed rails.
Once installed I create a application with

```
$ rails new my_app
```

and I ran the rail server from the directory of the application.

```
~/rails_projects/my_app$ rails server
```

The problem is that after exiting the application when I go to that directory later I can't run the server  this second time.

```
~/rails_projects/my_app$ rails server

Could not find gem 'spring (>= 0) ruby' in the gems available on this machine.
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

It doesn't show any Rails version from that directory but yes from the home directory:

```
~$ rails -v
Rails 4.1.1

~/rails_projects/my_app$ rails -v

Could not find gem 'spring (>= 0) ruby' in the gems available on this machine.
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems
```

Comment: Did you run `bundle install`?

Comment: mmm, if you are at home directory `rails new my_app` will creates your app in `~/my_app` not in `~/rails_projects/my_app` are you sure you are in the right path?

Comment: A lot of times if it was working, then stops, you are likely using a version manager like rvm that uses a different gemset (set of installed gems) than what rails expects. Unfortunately you may have to do some sleuthing. Try bundle install, and see what it says. I would look up rvm to see if that is in play too, and learn to use the basic commands to change and create gemsets. Might help. http://rvm.io/

Answer (score 1):

It seams you are starting with Rails. Please follow the [official guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) to get an inside of the framework.

To get started you need to create a project:

```
$ rails new my_app
```

then go the project directory:

```
$ cd my_app
```

install dependencies (if you add any to your Gemfile):

```
$ bundle install
```

and then run the server

```
$ rails server
```

Again, if you are starting follow that guide!

Comment: `rails new my_app` runs `bundle install` so the step is not necessary. The link you post says that.